# Augmentation of Promise breaks type inference for new Promise(...)

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to augment Promise by adding extra method to it as described in the TypeScript documentation - [Global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation).

And it works well in the test 1. But for some reason it breaks type inference for the Promise created using constructor in the test 2. TypeScript stops inferring type as `Promise<boolean>` and infers it as `Promise<{}>` instead. If I remove my augmentation, generic type for `Promise` created using constructor is inferred correctly.

Any ideas why it happens and how to fix it?

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
// src/test.ts

// augmentation
interface Promise<T> {
    myCustomMethod(): T;
}

// test 1
let data: number = Promise.resolve(42)
    .then((value) => value + 4)
    .myCustomMethod();

// test 2
let p2: Promise<boolean> = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(true);
})
```

And my config:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "baseUrl": "./src"
    }
}
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
src/test.ts(9,5): error TS2322: Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<boolean>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

**UPD**

I see that type is always inferred as `Promise<{}>` for the test 2. But now I can't understand, why this error is not reported without my augmentation. Since `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`, shouldn't this error appear even without augmentation?

Just trying to understand if it's intended or should I report it to TypeScript developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript always infers Promise<{}> type for this construct, even without your augmentation:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true);
})
```

as evidenced by error message for this assignment:

```
let z: void = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true);
})
```

> Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'void'

So, when you add `myCustomMethod(): T;` to `Promise`, as a side effect it  makes `Promise<{}>` incompatible with `Promise<boolean>`.

Either don't do that (when you call `myCustomMethod()` on unresolved promise, where will it get the `T` value it should return?) , or use explicit generic argument when constructing your promise:

```
let p2: Promise<boolean> = new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
    resolve(true);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and workaround. Please, take a look at the updated question. Can you elaborate why error doesn't appear without my augmentation?

Comment: Because without your augmentation, `T` appears in `Promise` only as a function argument type, and TypeScript has [function compatibility rules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) that make `function(x: {})` compatible with `function(x: boolean)`, because `boolean` can be assigned to `{}`.  Having `T` as return value makes them incompatible because `{}` can't be assigned to `boolean`.

Comment: Here is an [example demonstrating  compatibility for function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20f1%20%3D%20function%20(x%3A%20boolean)%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20f2%20%3D%20function%20(x%3A%20%7B%7D)%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Af1%20%3D%20f2%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0Af2%20%3D%20f1%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20f3%20%3D%20function%20()%3A%20boolean%20%7B%20return%20true%7D%3B%0D%0Avar%20f4%20%3D%20function%20()%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7B%20return%20%7B%7D%7D%3B%0D%0Af3%20%3D%20f4%3B%20%2F%2F%20not%20ok%0D%0Af4%20%3D%20f3%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can infer the type of a generic from the argument in simple cases like calling `Promise.resolve()` with a constant in `Promise.resolve(42)`. It may fail to do so in more complex situations, like when the type only becomes apparent in your call to `resolve(true)` .

This is documented in the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

> While type argument inference can be a helpful tool to keep code shorter and more readable, you may need to explicitly pass in the type arguments as we did in the previous example when the compiler fails to infer the type, as may happen in more complex examples.

You can work around the issue by using

```
let p2: Promise<boolean> = new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
   resolve(true);
});
```